# Is any dense set also total?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

The definition of a *total* set according to the [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Total_set) is:

> A set $M⊂T$, where $T$ is a topological vector space, is called a total set or fundamental set if the linear span of $M$ is dense in $T$.

If $M$ is **already** dense in $T$, does that ensure that it is also total in $T$?

Context: I am looking at a proof where a set is assumed to be total in another, however the author works only with the density of the supposedly total set, and not with the closure of it's linear span. This has lead me to wonder whether it is sufficient to work the density of the original set alone, and not with the closure of it's linear span.

Comment: A set containing a dense set is dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear span of a set contains the set itself, so the linear span of a dense set has a dense subset, so it is also dense.

Comment: Picking this up after a while: you mention that "the linear span of a dense set **has a dense subset**, so **it** is also dense"; I have been looking for a reference for this result but haven't had any luck so far. So, is it a general result that in a metric space $M$, if in $A\subset B\subset M$ we have that $A$ is dense in $M$ then both $B$ and $M$ are also dense?

Comment: Yes. Indeed, if $A \subset B \subset M$, the closures of $A$ and $B$ satisfy $\overline{A} \subset \overline{B} \subset M$ in $M$. So if $A$ is dense in $M$, i.e. $\overline{A}=M$, then you have $\overline{B} = M$, i.e. $B$ is also dense in $M$. Note that this is true in any topological space, even non-metric.